# Why when using console.log() to print out a string inside a function it duplicates the output result?

Tags: javascript

When declaring the below function I receive the output twice

```
  var orangeCost = function (orange) {
        var price = orange * 5
        console.log(price);
        console.log(" is the price")
    }

        orangeCost(5)
```

Comment: You are lucky, I get it [__once__](http://jsfiddle.net/rt8dp/)

Comment: I can only assume that you're somehow calling `orangeCost()` more than once. Perhaps inside a loop that's not included here?

Comment: Looks fine to me - can you add the code where you call the function?

Comment: Did you want your function to return something to the caller?